# Register device id directly with Amazon SNS

Tags: android, notifications, push, amazon-sns

I am using the [Amazon Web Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMobilePush.html) to send push notifications directly to a device. After I install the app I get the device id, that I need to manually add to the Amazon SNS. I would like to know if there is anyway to register the device id directly with the amazon server the moment the user starts the application.

I have read [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send-devicetoken.html), but found it difficult to understand. Does anyone have any previous experience of how to do this?

**EDIT 2 (What I have done so far)**

I've followed the instructions from [this link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-gcm.html)

1. I download the snspobilepush.zip file as instructed and extract and import the project into eclipse. I add the GCM project number, add the jar files and run the application. I get my device registration Id.
2. I open the Amazon SNS, add my device id and I publish a message. I receive the message on my mobile phone. Works great so far.

   **MY PROBLEM**

I would be having a lot of potential users for my application. So adding every device id manually to the SNS makes no sense. I need the Amazon SNS to directly register my device id when I start the app. Is there any option for me to do that? I couldn't  find any definitive answer in the docs.
[This link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send-devicetoken.html) tells me to Use the "AWS Token Vending Service". However, I could not find any example of how to do that.

Answer (score 11):

Using the AmazonSNSClient documented here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/

it should be possible to register using code similar to this:

```
AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("XXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
String platformApplicationArn = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789:app/GCM/myappname";
AmazonSNSClient pushClient = new AmazonSNSClient(awsCredentials);

String customPushData = "my custom data";
CreatePlatformEndpointRequest platformEndpointRequest = new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest();
platformEndpointRequest.setCustomUserData(customPushData);
platformEndpointRequest.setToken(pushNotificationRegId);
platformEndpointRequest.setPlatformApplicationArn(platformApplicationArn);
CreatePlatformEndpointResult result = pushClient.createPlatformEndpoint(platformEndpointRequest);
Log.w(TAG, "Amazon Push reg result: " + result);
```

It was not liking my ARN, but that was a stupid typo that Reid pointed out and is now fixed above.

Comment: I'm from PH, and while my internets is probably routed in AUS (office setup, don't ask), I don't understand why this only works when I create my SNS app in US-East. Will probably ask a different question for that, but since this works, it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I replaced mine with my own `platformApplicationArn`.

Comment: For anybody else running in to the region error using this approach as I was, my solution was to manually set the region on the SNSClient.

`pushClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));`

Comment: I used the code above with my credentials, but I get an error : `MissingAuthenticationToken`. I've checked the credentials and they correspond to the one amazon gives me... Any idea where I can get this token ?

Comment: @josephus what is 'pushNotificationRegId' I can't resolve it in my code?

Answer (score 1):

There is Android AWS SDK available to use. Check out the documentation link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/

Also, more information available: http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/

Comment: I've been through both those links. I feel like I'm going around in circles. The instructions are very poorly documented.

Comment: Could you please share the code you have tried so far. What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: Hello again! The code works fine, and I don't get any error. I only need to register the device id with the Amazon server directly which I am not able to do (instead of me manually having to add it). I've edited my question to include this. Pls have a look. Thanks!

Comment: The way I handle this is by having my backend php code to do this. However, since I know that this can be done by AwsSDK the link I sent you. It is just a learning curve you need to go thru. look into IAM roles as your SDK need the credentials  to communicate with Amazon resources.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for Firebase and Cognito. An AsyncTask is necessary to avoid running on the Main Thread.

```
private class RegisterIdForAWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        private Exception exception;

        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                String pushNotificationRegId = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

                if (pushNotificationRegId != null) {

                    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider provider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "us-west-2:aaaaaaaaa-1234-1234-1234-0bbbbbbbbbbbb",
                            Regions.US_WEST_2);
                    String platformApplicationArn = "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789:app/GCM/appname";
                    AmazonSNSClient pushClient = new AmazonSNSClient(provider);
                    pushClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));

                    String customPushData = "";
                    CreatePlatformEndpointRequest platformEndpointRequest = new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest();
                    platformEndpointRequest.setCustomUserData(customPushData);
                    platformEndpointRequest.setToken(pushNotificationRegId);
                    platformEndpointRequest.setPlatformApplicationArn(platformApplicationArn);
                    CreatePlatformEndpointResult result = pushClient.createPlatformEndpoint(platformEndpointRequest);
                    Log.w(TAG, "Amazon Push reg result: " + result);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                this.exception = e;
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String text) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Amazon Push reg Finished");
        }
    }
```