# What is the most efficient way to create end-points for an Amazon SNS service?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

I am using Amazon SNS Service for an iOS application that needs push notifications.

I have figured most of the things, except for the part where I have to register my device tokens.

[This](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send-devicetoken.html) is where Amazon talks about it. It can be done manually or with the help of createPlatformEndpoint API which they obviously recommend for bulk uploads. My question is how we can directly register tokens from devices that will install the app later on. The documentation talks about a proxy server which I would want to avoid as of now. Isn't there a direct way of doing this, like where I can directly call a method and push the device token received in the application to my SNS Platform?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782653/register-device-id-directly-with-amazon-sns), is a possible duplicate except that it is in reference to Android.

Answer (score 5):

The [AWS Mobile SDKs](http://aws.amazon.com/mobile) support accessing SNS directly from the mobile device.  If you're interested in seeing code demonstrating this on iOS, we included some as a sample we prepared for re:Invent 2013 called [Mobile Photo Share](https://github.com/awslabs/reinvent2013-mobile-photo-share).

The important thing to note when accessing SNS directly from the mobile device is that you'll want to restrict the credentials delivered to the device to only those services and resources you'll need to access. You can accomplish this via [web identity federation](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4617974389850313) or a [token vending machine](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4611615499399490) with appropriately restricted policy.

If you want to learn more about the Mobile Photo Share app, we had two talks at re:Invent about the app and its architecture. The video and slides for those talks are available here:

- [Building Cloud-Backed Mobile Apps](http://bit.ly/1bPG0mx)
- [Integrating Social Login Into Mobile Apps](http://bit.ly/1fDgMP9)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Bob. I will go over the slides and the video you referred and get back.