# Get AuthorizationErrorException when try create a EndPoint (Android&AWS)

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I would like register the customers directly when I get the RegisterId......This is the same idea....
[Register device id directly with Amazon SNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782653/register-device-id-directly-with-amazon-sns)

Of course, I change the credentials and put my access_key_id, secret_access_key and my arn but don't work....I get a....

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.AuthorizationErrorException: User: arn:aws:iam::074319215995:user/diogo10 is not authorized to perform: SNS:CreatePlatformEndpoint on resource: arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:074319215995:app/GCM/ApiProject (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AuthorizationError; Request ID: b86b1bfc-f2c4-5ea9-a514-56a9b6df2e4d)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(Unknown Source)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(Unknown Source)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

My code is....

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(access_key_id, secret_access_key);
String platformApplicationArn = "arn:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/GCM/ApiProject";
AmazonSNSClient pushClient = new AmazonSNSClient(awsCreds);
pushClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1));

String customPushData = "my custom data";
CreatePlatformEndpointRequest platformEndpointRequest = new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest();
platformEndpointRequest.setCustomUserData(customPushData);
platformEndpointRequest.setToken(regId);
platformEndpointRequest.setPlatformApplicationArn(platformApplicationArn);
CreatePlatformEndpointResult result = pushClient.createPlatformEndpoint(platformEndpointRequest);
Log.i(TAG, "Amazon Push reg result: " + result);
```

Comment: check your credentials..

Comment: How can I check it ? because for example...I can upload a file in S3..but now I can't do it =/

Comment: Hey !...I found a way....go to IAM Management Console and create a group  with suit permission, after, put your user.

Comment: Yes from there you can also set permissions to the single user, thats what i did...